# How to open a fragment on clicking to RecyclerView item which is implemented in another fragment which is again can be swiped by using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager consisting of 5 fragments. Have a RecyclerView in the first fragment showing list of dishes items.
I have implemented click listeners on the RecyclerView items, **but** now I want to open a fragment that would show more information about the dish clicked and this fragment should replace the fragment that is holding RecyclerView and is **not** one of the 5 fragment of ViewPager.

How can I call the **Dish information** fragment with the click listener inside of RecyclerView item, inside of a fragment controlled by ViewPager so as to replace the former ViewPager fragment with the Dish Information Fragment?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to open up the fragment inside the onClick method of RecyclerView item by  dish_info dish_info = new dish_info();
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewPager,dish_info,"findMe").addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: when I click on the item it throws exception saying for the MainActivity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new fragment i.e. dish detail fragment.
Now on recycler view list item click replace your existing fragment with itemDetail fragment.
Example:- I am supposing that your container view is "R.id.fragmentContainer" and in this container your are loading the fragment.

Now just call this code on recyclerView item click

```
    ItemDetailFragment itemDetailFragment=new ItemDetailFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(animSlideIn, animSlideOut, animSlideIn, animSlideOut);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, itemDetailFragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: what is that 'fragmentContainer', I have a ViewPager !

Comment: This is a view in your parent layout in which you are loading your 5 tab fragment. i use dummy name (it can be Framelayout, fragment or any other layout).So fragment container is just a fragment container id